# Вопрос по Char, его размер

Tags: c, строки

подскажите пожалуйста почему надо писать в Char[1024] в скобках 1024, размер Char'a вроде всего 1 байт?

Comment: А размер `char[1024]` - **массива из 1024 `char`** - 1024 байта...

Comment: не обязательно, сколько нужно, столько и пишите и в квадратных скобках

Answer (score 1):

Char[1024] это создание строки(массив символов) размером в 1024 символа. Тоесть если тебе нужно, к примеру строка размером в 100000 символов, тебе нужно написать Char[100000]